# Ansible AWX - What AWX stands for?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I just wonder what AWX of Ansible AWX (Ansible Tower upstream project) stands for?

Something or just 3 cool letters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AWX in Ansible AWX stands for **Ansible WorX**

It is found inside this commit https://github.com/ansible/awx/commit/5c6895e6065a81f4483dfb6bc7650706f8866e1e

They used an **X** instead of **ks**

Comment: It would be great if you could add some reference to this answer.

Comment: Reference: https://groups.google.com/g/awx-project/c/DncUXeoZUUg?pli=1

If you google Ansible WorX it's obvious^^

Comment: And all this time I thought it was Ansible Web eXperience...